# How to send mail without login with Gmail API?

Tags: c#, .net-core, gmail, gmail-api, google-developers-console

Good work everyone,
Gmail API also requires user approval. But I have no idea how to use the token. I have to send a control mail to the user. Can I do without tokens?
I am making request with HttpClient. I am not using credentials.json.
As a postman, I can take and take tokens, but the token must not be renewed.
Sorry for my English. Thanks

I tried sending mail with Smtp Server. But it is blocked for security reasons. The only healthy solution is to send mail via Gmail API.

Comment: If you have doubts on how to use Gmail API with C# you can check [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet). You can't use Gmail API without OAuth Authorization, the only possible solution is use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)

Comment: I wrote something here about using Gmail (through Google Workspace) that you may find useful: https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-send-emails-from-csharp-net-the-definitive-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SMTP:

```
public class EmailService
{
    public Task Execute(string UserEmail, string Body, string Subject)
    {
        //enable less secure apps in account google with link
        //https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
        try
        {


            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 587;
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Timeout = 1000000;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***email here****", "****password here****");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage("***email here****", UserEmail, Subject, Body);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
            message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
            client.Send(message);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.Write(e);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Also as mentioned in comment, enable less secure apps in google account.
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

hint: less secure can't be enabled for emails with 2-step verification.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried to send it with SmtpClient, but I found out that it works with the .NET 6.0 version MailClient library. It worked when I added the MailClient. It didn't work with standard System.Net.
I also had to apply the low security account setting.